# Передача файла из 1С на SharePoint через SQL

Tags: 1с, sharepoint

Стоит задача передачи файла для отображении как вложение в web-форме на сайте SharePoint.

Сам файл .htm формирует 1С. Есть идея перевода файла в бинарник, записи данных в поле таблицы SQL и чтение и преобразовании его в файл на стороне сайта. Но с чтением и преобразованием проблемы - нет опыта.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) или PowerShell

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-import-data-from-html-pages/